# Confusing compilation errors from CLANG

Tags: string, c++11, gcc, clang++, allocator

I am trying to write a custom allocator for `char` to be used with `std::basic_string`. I wrote following code, but it fails to compile using **x86 clang 3.7** on *gcc.godbolt.org* — see [the code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4CGUDmB7ATiAFwAsBbAPgChRJZFUBnA%2FMTS66eZFEbR3BNOSrgOdFAQCeABwQB9JmkL02I2lwh9wrCjoIISUqGj2pJMsIOQAVKZT4wIBJCQmyMUbBGN4kAbwoAvgDcuvqGxlx2TA5OLm5QHl4EeCgQRGi4ZH4USLlIaRlIGbgA2gDMAAwAuiG5ZgiIAGb56bhIAG4YMHL1tc6u7p7euAAUAJQ52Xl5jHAAXHMQ2DAEKCgARI54ADpg630Bk3oGRiapRvT0SFZZk3GDSXgjS2CM%2FfGJwyg3AGRI2MQELgJrl%2FNNcrMFksVmtNtgpK4trhdvtJtNIXMSPoIAiRsUADQAohAgB0BMqYwOkwKuAAVEUEkM9CMMfQQAAvHpIEFTcEY6GrDYPCJwFF9ab8AgwXBgIq4XBU3LtbAgOBIRDC5k0%2Bn4pCsjlcnlgvkEeaLZaC9aNfgNMWTQ7BXTSBoIZoYgBGaDZEFkmhYqVa%2BP5rXkuEUBHoAYyZF190Zj1wUcySCycT9mBCFHAsUUYHGFGNuTTTC0RRG62JjPWlLRetNUItazQIQCQAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang37x%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%22%7D%5D%7D). GCC, on the other hand, compiles it successfully.

As usual, there are lots of error messages, one of them being:

```
error: 'rebind' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
```

My work so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>


template <typename Tp>
struct my_allocator {
};

template <>
struct my_allocator<char> {
    char arr[30];
  typedef char value_type;
  my_allocator()
  {
      std::cout<<"ctor\n";
  }
  template <class T> 
  my_allocator(const my_allocator<T>& other)
  {
      std::cout<<"copy_ctor\n";
      std::memcpy(arr,other.arr,30);
  }
  char* allocate(std::size_t )
  {
      std::cout<<"allocated\n";
      return arr;
  }
  void deallocate(char* , std::size_t )
  {
      std::cout<<"freed\n";
  }
};

typedef std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>, my_allocator<char> > my_string;

int main()
{
    my_string a("hello");
    std::cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: Works fine on this clang3.7 + x86_64 + stdlibc++ combination: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/facf661ab6e8c169

Comment: clang is misconfigured there, it selects a too old version of libstdc++.

Comment: @dyp please be more careful with the names you use, you probably meant either libstdc++ or libc++, not stdlibc++...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry, that was a mere typo. I meant libstdc++, as shown in the compiler options of my coliru link.